# Serial communication with other devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, usbserial

I am developing an app for my own use. Android device communicates with other devices. Earlier i was communicating via `Bluetooth`, but at the moment i am changing to `USB` communication. I use [ksksue FTDriver](https://github.com/ksksue/FTDriver). And i ran into thinking loop and can't break from it :)

Basically, there are fixed 6 bytes data i need to receive from device. 2 data bytes and 4 CRC bytes. I was taking 1 byte by 1 and adding it to other byte array, when reach 6 bytes then recopy them to new byte arrays and deal with them if CRC equal.

This is from Bluetooth app

```
public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytesAvailable; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytesAvailable = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, input_bytes_from, last, buffer.length);
                    last++;
                    if (last == 6){
                        last = 0;
                        Log.d(TAG,"received "+bytesToHex(input_bytes_from));
                    byte[] data_bytes = new byte[2];
                    byte[] crc_to_compare = new byte[4];

                    for(byte i=0;i<data_bytes.length;i++)data_bytes[i] = input_bytes_from[i];

                    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                        crc_to_compare[i] = input_bytes_from[i+data_bytes.length]; 
                       }
                    crc_test(data_bytes,crc_to_compare);

                    }
                }
                  catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
```

- What happens to byte/s when `bytesAvailable = mmInStream.read(buffer);` is called? Is one byte copied and deleted from `mmInStream.read`?
- Is there faster and better way to do this? Because as i understand copying one by one byte is slow?

Answer (score 0):

- What happens to byte/s when `bytesAvailable = mmInStream.read(buffer);` is called? Is one byte copied and deleted from `mmInStream.read`?

Yes. One byte is removed from the `InputStream`, and the byte is copied into the `buffer`.

- Is there faster and better way to do this? Because as i understand copying one by one byte is slow?

You don't need to read bytes one by one. Refer to the following code.

```
public void run() {
    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[] data_bytes = new byte[2];
            byte[] crc_to_compare = new byte[4];

            mmInStream.read(data_bytes);
            mmInStream.read(crc_to_compare);

            crc_test(data_bytes, crc_to_compare);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

There is an open source framework for serial communication with other devices, called NFCommunicator.

https://github.com/Neofect/NFCommunicator

It could help you make an Android application which talks to other devices via serial protocol like Bluetooth SPP, though it is not for USB connection at the moment.